# My jquery is loading, but won't run in file

Tags: jquery, debugging

My Jquery loader is at the very top of the header, and I know it is loading, but when I try to use Jquery functions in a file, they don't work, but they don't throw an error either. Here's the Jquery loader:

```
<head>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Social Idler || An Incremental</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link href="css/paper-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Self made styleing -->
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css"rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

Here's the Jquery in the file that won't run:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(save));
}, 1000);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("jquery works!");
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
});
```

The console isn't logging "jquery works!". Nor is it saving and loading the save var.

EDIT: I had misspelled the word script while assigning the save file in my html.

Comment: Please post the jquery loader, because running this in a fiddle, the console works http://jsfiddle.net/ytauenr6/

Comment: where does `save` get defined?

Comment: save gets defined in another file, I can share that as well.

Comment: Is that path for the jquery 100% correct? Perhaps think about using a CDN like you did for bootstrap.

Comment: I'll try using a CDN, but what would cause this to happen? Had a similiar problem with bootstrap, which is why I'm using a CDN there. So it's most likely something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: No, a CDN still isn't logging that to the console.

Comment: where is your jquery logic (the file including your code snippet with the console.log) and are you including that file correctly into your html?

Comment: I'm an idiot... I misspelled script...